# Seeking hinge for a fold-back desk that flips up and out

Tags: hinges

I am renovating the closet in my daughter's room to make it a little study nook with a loft.  To save space, I'd like the desk to fold back against the wall inside the closet.  When not in use, the desk should sit flush against the wall on the inside of the closet.  When she needs to use it, I'd like her to be able to flip the desk first up and then out from the closet, so that she can sit on the edge of the loft and work with the desk in front of her.

I was thinking I can do this with a "flip" hinge, sort of like the ones you see in auditorium desks where the desk tucks under the armrest (to use those, you first pull the desk up and then turn it sideways across your lap).  I was thinking I could bolt that to the inside wall of the closet and use it like an auditorium desk, but with the flip re-oriented.

I'd love to hear if anyone has tried that, or knows where to get a flip hinge like I'm describing.  I'm not even sure what to Google for!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is the size of the desk top?

Comment: Does it have to relying on a hinges? There are other ways to get the same result you ask for.

Comment: Having difficulty envisioning this.  Walk-in closet?  Height of loft?  Wall framing and surface materials?  More info will probably help us help.

Comment: Thanks!  I came up with another way to do it using a cross section of two metal pipes.